# MVVM - handling Disposable-s in ViewModel with RxJava and Room

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-room, android-viewmodel

I try to apply the MVVM pattern in my Android activity (I'm an Android noob).

I use Room with RxJava 2, e.g. this is a signature of a method in my repository:

```
public Single<MissionTask> getMissionTaskByID(long id) {..}
```

In my **ViewModel** class I have a reference to the repository and code like this:

```
private void doSomethingOnUserEvent() {
    ...
      missionTaskRepository.getMissionTaskByID(firstID).
          observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
          subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
          subscribe(missionTask ->
              {
                // do some work and update live data
              },
              t -> {
                // handle error
              });
    ...
  }
```

So far so good, everything seems to work fine on the surface. Now - `subscribe` returns a `Disposable`.

My questions are:

1. How should I handle the disposable (e.g. I can put it in a composite disposable and dispose the composite when the model is cleared)?
2. What will happen if I do not dispose it? Leak? Why?

In some of the examples I've gone through there is no handling of the Disposable.

**Update:** I've seen the usage of [composite disposable](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/ui/UserActivity.java) in [android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components).

Thanks.

Comment: Use `onCleared` ...example of doing this in https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/viewmodel/BusRoutesViewModel.kt

Comment: Look it might help : https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d

Answer (score 7):

Just clear your disposable/composite disposible in `onCleared`, this is enough

```
protected override onCleared(){
    if( diposable != null )
        disposable.dispose()
}
```

Comment: I guessed that and saw how to use composite disposable. But why should I do that with Room? :-)

Comment: why you shouldn't? you should always dispose ongoing action when your viewmodel is destroyed, with a Single this is indeed not as a big deal than an Observable since it may dispose itself eventually but could be after onCleard though

Comment: Maybe it would be a best practice to use subscribe with SingleObserver in a case when handling Single?